# How to format a float in python which has variable number of zeros after decimal point?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, format, precision

I have a function that returns a float number which can have from 0 to up to 8 zeros after the decimal point.

I want to format the float in non-scientific notation and display only up to 4 non-zero digits following the zeros after the decimal point.

For example:

```
1.42 should be formatted as 1.42  
1.4205152 should be formatted as 1.4205  
1.42e-2 should be formatted as 0.0142  
1.452e-4 should be formatted as 0.0001452  
1.49315e-5 should be formatted as 0.00001493
```

etc

Is there a format specifier in python to do so, or writing a custom function is the only solution?

Comment: Have you looked at the `format` function?

Comment: Yes; I did. But doesn't the format function only takes argument for a fixed number of digits after decimal point? i.e. {0.xf}.format will give me x digits after decimal point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in support for this. That is, there is no format specifier or conversion function that does this directly. You will need to write your own code to do the formatting.

Comment: Thank you for that piece of information. I'll proceed to write one without worrying about reinventing the wheel.